# Branch of mathematics that deals with repeated operations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, arithmetic, exponentiation, tetration

One interesting trait of subtraction is that it can introduce us to negative numbers using just positive whole numbers. For instance, $1-3=-2$. Division, similarly, can introduce us to a new set of numbers: decimals and fractions. For instance, $3/2=1.5$. Square roots can also show us a new set of numbers: imaginary. $\sqrt{-1}=i$.

The significance of this is that these operations are all inverses of operations that result from repeating a lower level function. If you could assign a number to this, you could say addition is 1. Multiplication is repeated addition, so it is 2 (it is defined as repeating a level 1 function). Exponentiation would be 3 (it is defined as repeating a level 2 function). Is there any branch of mathematics that deals with how properties of functions change as you go to higher levels? For example, exponentiation is not commutative ($3^2\neq2^3$). This is different from both addition and multiplication, both components of exponentiation (it is repeated multiplication, which is repeated addition). I believe I heard somewhere that as you get a level higher, one property changes, but that may have just been a theory of mine.

Is there any branch of mathematics that specifically deals with the properties of different levels of functions?

Another, perhaps deeper question involves stretching the limits of mathematics. If we do indeed have a branch of mathematics where people study functions in this way, is there such thing as a level 0 function? Some function that is more fundamental than addition? If there is a study of these operations, mathematics would find a way to answer all of these questions. what about a level -1? i? $\pi$?

Comment: You might be interested in things things like the Ackermann function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) and the repeated "up arrow" notation. Also the Conway Chained Arrow notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation) and Tetration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). You will note that these all involve language/notation for repeated operations beyond exponentiation, without being a "branch of mathematics"

Comment: @MarkBennet I have heard about tetration before, but the other two are new to me. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: The Tetration article references the others. The Knuth Up Arrow notation also has a useful article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) and is perhaps the most familiar general extension. But there are limits on what can be achieved, because with a finite number of symbols we can only describe countably many things, and the subsets of the natural numbers are uncountable. So there are subsets which grow faster than we will ever be able to describe.

Comment: @MarkBennet Actually, I have found that tetration is also evidence for the statement I remember. $^{a}(^{b}c)\neq^{ab}c$, while $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$. That means that tetration had lost that property that exponentiation had. Tetration is a level 4 function according to my theory. This makes me think that there is a common understanding of what I'm talking about, because "tetra-" literally means four.

Comment: The Knuth notation gives you also 5, 6, 7 ... The Ackermann function is closely related. The Conway notation is an economical way of expressing ridiculously large numbers (eg see the bounds on Graham's Number in the article)

Comment: Mark Neyrinck’s May 1995 undergraduate thesis [**An Investigation of Arithmetic Operations**](http://skysrv.pha.jhu.edu/~neyrinck/extessay.pdf) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Your question deals with concerns that are currently met in **computer science** (not astonishing that Knuth is mentionned for example) ; the concept of "level" is encountered for example in compilers, the lowest being the hardware level. Another direction I could advise is $\lambda$-calculus formalizing the concept of "calculability".

Comment: Just for smiling: the ***inequality*** $2^4 \ne 4^2$ is one of the most curious inequalities I've ever seen :-)

Comment: - Don't know about other places, but in the "tetration-forum" there is/has been a discussion about "zeration", an attempted binary operations "below" addition.

Comment: Do you know the term "hyperoperation"? (see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) In the wp.article even "zeration" is mentioned with a link to G.F. Romario (who discussed this as well in the tetration-forum - and reading *discussions* often has additional pedagogical value...). I liked Markus Müller's explorative "Reihenalgebra" much which he wrote in its first edition as a high-school pupil, this is as well linked in the "hyperoperation" entry in wikipedia.

Comment: One more: MSE has the tag "function-and-relation-composition". "Self-composition" of functions were then the aspect for which you should find much valuable input following that tag.

Comment: Many questions on iterated functions are under MSE tag "dynamical systems"; as well as under "complex analysis" (don't know whether you are interested on the iteration of functions/operation over complex numbers, though)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Wow I chose like the only one that doesn't work

Comment: :-) Yes, this is something so sweet to tell to the grandchildren that such has happened... . Any epsilon value different from your choice would have had made it a correct one...

Comment: There is a post on mathoverflow that might interest you: https://mathoverflow.net/q/440181/41139

Answer (score 1):

Without being a "branch of mathematics" at all, you find repeated operations like :

$A=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\cdots}}}}\tag{1}$

(belonging to the category of "continued fractions") or :

$$B=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}\tag{2}$$

the first question being whether they **really** define a number. In fact, if such is the case

- for (1), taking the inverse of both sides and adding one to them, we get the necessary condition $A=1+\dfrac{1}{1+A}$ which is equivalent to a quadratic equation with (one of its) solution(s) $A = \sqrt{2}$.
- for (2), a similar process gives $A=\sqrt{1+A}$, yielding as well a quadratic equation with (one of its) solution(s) $B = \frac12(1+\sqrt{5})\approx 1.618\cdots$, the golden ratio.

In fact both of them fall into a general category which is the rigorous definition of numbers as limits of recursive sequences :

$$u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$$

with a certain initial value $u_0$ with different functions $f$.

Not all $f$ and not all $u_0$ (far from that) giving rise to a convergent behavior...